# How to get text of all options of dropdown in Selenium Webdriver using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx

I am able to get total number of options but not able to get text.

Comment: What you want? Are you talikng about the select list values? or what..Could you be specific please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me with or without using `Selenium::WebDriver::Wait`.

Here is the complete code (I commented out the version without using [WebDriverWait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits), both versions should work anyway):

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get('http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx')

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds

# without wait
# combo = driver.find_element(:id => 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadComboBox1_Input')
# combo.click

# with wait
combo = wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadComboBox1_Input") }
combo.click

# without wait
# all_labels = driver.find_elements(:css => '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadComboBox1_DropDown .rcbItem label')

# with wait
all_labels = wait.until { driver.find_elements(:css => '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadComboBox1_DropDown .rcbItem label') }
all_labels.each do |label|
  puts label.text
end
puts all_labels.count
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following. It's working at my end:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.get "http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx"

el = driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadComboBox1_Arrow")
el.click

list = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//ul[@class='rcbList']")
options = list.find_elements(:xpath, ".//li/label")
options.each do |option|
    puts option.text
end
```